# Angular $http Interceptor Opens Multiple Modals When Auth Fails

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-http-auth

I am using the `$http interceptor` to show a login modal when `$auth` fails. Here is a brief set-up I have:

```
$provide.factory('modalWhenLoggedOut', ['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope',
          function($q, $injector, $rootScope) {

        return {

             responseError: function(rejection) {

                 // $injector.get to fix circular dependency error
                 var loginModal = $injector.get('LoginModalService');
                 var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                 var $state = $injector.get('$state');

                 // Check for reasons instead of status code
                 var rejectionReasons = ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired', 'token_absent', 'token_invalid'];

                 // Loop through each rejection reason and redirect
                 angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function(value, key) {

                     if(rejection.data.error === value) {
                        // Show the login modal
                         var deferred = $q.defer();

                         loginModal()
                           .then(function () {
                             deferred.resolve( $http(rejection.config) );
                         })
                         .catch(function () {
                             $state.go('index');
                             deferred.reject(rejection);
                        });

                        return deferred.promise;
                     }
                 });

                 return $q.reject(rejection);
             }
         }
}]);

// Push the new factory onto the $http interceptor array
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('modalWhenLoggedOut');
```

The above code works fine. But the problem I have is when the api throws multiple auth failure error, the interceptor opens up multiple modals at the same time. Usually in 1 page I might have 2-3 times various services contacting the backend api and when the auth fails, all of those api returns auth failure error during invalid tokens. This interceptor is picking it up as 3 taken_invalid errors and showing 3 login modals 1 on top of each other. How do I prevent this?

**How can I make sure the interceptor only shows 1 login modal no matter how many times the auth failure occurred?**

My Service Looks something like this:

```
.service('LoginModalService', ['$modal', '$rootScope', 
            function($modal, $rootScope) {

                    function updateRootScope() {
                            $rootScope.loginProgress = false;
                    }

                  if ($rootScope.loginProgress = false) {
                    return function() {
                      var instance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: rootPath + 'views/partials/LoginModalTemplate.html',
                        controller: 'LoginModalCtrl'
                      })

                    return instance.result.then(updateRootScope);
                  };
                  }
}])
```

In the service I am trying to use `$rootScope.loginProgress` as a switch to figure out if a login modal is opened or not. However, I am not sure how to return an empty promise if modal is already opened (when `$rootScope.loginProgress` is true).

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your "responseError" function in a service that has a flag to check wether the modal has been displayed already or not?

Comment: not yet. I am right now trying to store `modalopen` in localstorage and check that in foreach loop. Not sure if that method will work. I will update back if I had any luck on that.,

Comment: @XelharK I am thinking storing in `$rootScope` is better than storing in `localStorage`. Taking your suggestion, I thought I can perhaps use the `$rootScope` as a switch by setting `$rootScope.loginProgress` as true when modal opens and the consecutive modals check this before deciding the open the modal or not. However, I am not sure how to return an empty promise to interceptor when `$rootScope.loginProgress` is true. I have updated my question with my service attempt. Can you help me on how I can proceed here please?

Comment: thanks heaps for your comment yesterday @XelharK That helped me in finally resolving my issue. I decided to use the `http-auth-interceptor`  and then changing the `$rootScope.loginProgress` when the login modal is opened. This seems to work. I have added that as the answer. Do let me know if there is a better way to do it. Thank you so much for your help. Without your comment, I would not have gone forward on this. :) Cheers!

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I said. Sorry for not answering, I was away during the weekend. Anyway, I think you can wrap this all up in a service and use a simple configuration line in your conf file to do the binding, so you have the most modularity :)

Comment: wrapping it to a service is a neat idea. I will do that. Thanks again and hope you had a good weekend. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome my issue, I am now using `http-auth-interceptor` interceptor and then changing the `$rootScope.loginProgress` based on the login modal open status. The consecutive modals that are opened due to multiple 401s will check for this login modal status and then decides to open a modal or not. Using `http-auth-interceptor`, I am able to add the switch by watching the `'event:auth-loginRequired'`. Here is the code I am using:

```
scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {      
            if(!$rootScope.loginProgress) {
                        $rootScope.loginProgress = true;
                        LoginModalService()
                            .then(function () {
                              authService.loginConfirmed();
                                    $rootScope.loginProgress = false;
                          })
                          .catch(function () {
                              authService.loginCancelled();
                                    $rootScope.loginProgress = false;
                          });
            }
});
```

Where `LoginModalService()` is the service that opens the login modal.